# Flatten BigQuery nested field contents into new columns instead of rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some BigQuery data in the following format:

```
"thing": [
  {
    "name": "gameLost",
    "params": [
      {
        "key": "total_games",
        "val": {
          "str_val": "3",
          "int_val": null
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "games_won",
        "val": {
          "str_val": "2",
          "int_val": null
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "game_time",
        "val": {
          "str_val": "44",
          "int_val": null
        }
      }
    ],
    "dt_a": "1470625311138000",
    "dt_b": "1470620345566000"
  }
```

I'm aware of the FLATTEN() function that will result in an output of 3 rows like so:

```
+------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| thing.name | thing.dt_a       | event_dim.dt_b   | thing.params.key   | thing.params.val.str_val | thing.params.val.int_val |
+------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| gameLost   | 1470625311138000 | 1470620345566000 | total_games_played | 3                        | null                     |
|            |                  |                  |                    |                          |                          |
| gameLost   | 1470625311138000 | 1470620345566000 | games_won          | 2                        | null                     |
|            |                  |                  |                    |                          |                          |
| gameLost   | 1470625311138000 | 1470620345566000 | game_time          | 44                       | null                     |
+------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

where the higher level keys/values get repeated into new rows for each deeper level object.

However, I need to output the deeper key/values as entirely new columns, and not repeat fields so the results would look like this:

```
+------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+
| thing.name | thing.dt_a       | event_dim.dt_b   | total_games_played | games_won | game_time |
+------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+
| gameLost   | 1470625311138000 | 1470620345566000 | 3                  | 2         | 44        |
+------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

How can I do this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) makes this easier to express (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options"):

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT STRUCT(
    "gameLost" AS name,
    ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, val STRUCT<str_val STRING, int_val INT64>>>[
      STRUCT("total_games", STRUCT("3", NULL)),
      STRUCT("games_won", STRUCT("2", NULL)),
      STRUCT("game_time", STRUCT("44", NULL))] AS params,
    1470625311138000 AS dt_a,
    1470620345566000 AS dt_b) AS thing
)
SELECT
  (SELECT AS STRUCT thing.* EXCEPT (params)) AS thing,
  thing.params[OFFSET(0)].val.str_val AS total_games_played,
  thing.params[OFFSET(1)].val.str_val AS games_won,
  thing.params[OFFSET(2)].val.str_val AS game_time
FROM T;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+
|                                  thing                                  | total_games_played | games_won | game_time |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+
| {"name":"gameLost","dt_a":"1470625311138000","dt_b":"1470620345566000"} | 3                  | 2         | 44        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

If you don't know the order of the keys in the array, you can use subselects to extract the relevant values:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT STRUCT(
    "gameLost" AS name,
    ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, val STRUCT<str_val STRING, int_val INT64>>>[
      STRUCT("total_games", STRUCT("3", NULL)),
      STRUCT("games_won", STRUCT("2", NULL)),
      STRUCT("game_time", STRUCT("44", NULL))] AS params,
    1470625311138000 AS dt_a,
    1470620345566000 AS dt_b) AS thing
)
SELECT
  (SELECT AS STRUCT thing.* EXCEPT (params)) AS thing,
  (SELECT val.str_val FROM UNNEST(thing.params) WHERE key = "total_games") AS total_games_played,
  (SELECT val.str_val FROM UNNEST(thing.params) WHERE key = "games_won") AS games_won,
  (SELECT val.str_val FROM UNNEST(thing.params) WHERE key = "game_time") AS game_time
FROM T;
```

Comment: Love new features of Standard SQL!!! Really do! Meantime, I don't think you can rely on order/offset to retrieve keys' values - unless there is a guarantee of keys to be in that specific order  - which in my practice usually not a case

Comment: Thanks! I updated my answer to show how that could work too.

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant and @ElliottBrossard!  You guys got me started, but I ran into more issues when trying to apply to my more complicated data source.  I've opened a new related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860534/flatten-firebase-exports-to-bigquery-into-tables-where-1-row-1-event-nested-d

Answer (score 1):

Try below (Legacy SQL)

```
SELECT 
  thing.name AS name,
  thing.dt_a AS dt_a,
  thing.dt_b AS dt_b
  MAX(IF(thing.params.key = "total_games_played", INTEGER(thing.params.val.str_val), 0)) WITHIN RECORD AS total_games_played,
  MAX(IF(thing.params.key = "games_won", INTEGER(thing.params.val.str_val), 0)) WITHIN RECORD AS games_won,
  MAX(IF(thing.params.key = "game_time", INTEGER(thing.params.val.str_val), 0)) WITHIN RECORD AS game_time,
FROM YourTable
```

For Standard SQL you can try (inspired by Elliott's answer - important difference - array is ordered by key so order of key values is guaranteed)

```
WITH Temp AS (
  SELECT 
    (SELECT AS STRUCT thing.* EXCEPT (params)) AS thing,
    ARRAY(SELECT val.str_val AS val FROM UNNEST(thing.params) ORDER BY key) AS params
  FROM YourTable
)
SELECT 
  thing, 
  params[OFFSET(2)] AS total_games_played,
  params[OFFSET(1)] AS games_won,
  params[OFFSET(0)] AS game_time
FROM Temp
```

Note: If you have other keys in params - you should add WHERE clause to SELECT inside ARRAY